# How to disable Warnings for includes folders?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, warnings, compilation

I have to use some library, and have no power to change it or care about it,
EveryTime i compile a HUGE number of warnings popup. Useless things like

> : warning C4350: behavior change: 'std::auto_ptr<_Ty>::auto_ptr(std::auto_ptr_ref<_Ty>) 
>   throw()' called instead of 'std::auto_ptr<_Ty>::auto_ptr(std::auto_ptr<_Ty> &) throw()'

I want to complete disable Warnings to this specific library. |But still want to have warnings to my own code. Is it possible in Visual Studio 2010 ?

Comment: What is the root cause of this warning? Are you sure they are harmless?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[#pragma warning](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2c8f766e.aspx) is one option, though it's probably only feasible if you use precompiled headers or have very few source files in your own project.

```
#pragma warning (push)
#pragma warning (disable : 4350)
#include <third/party/headers/in/question.h>
#pragma warning (pop)
```

Answer (score 4):

Create your own header file ( like "your_ABCD.h" ) with the below code.

```
// In your_ABCD.h
#pragma once
#pragma warning (disable : 4350)
#include <their_ABCD.h>
#pragma warning (default : 4350)
```

Then, you can include "your_ABCD.h" instead of "their_ABCD.h" file.